# TSF Gives Different Results on Different Machines Despite Fixed NumPy Seed

Tags: python, numpy, random, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I have a time series forecasting application where the algorithm can be selected from 2 choices:

- sklearn Linear Regression
- statsmodels ARIMA vs. SARIMAX (based on the seasonality of the data)

There's no attribute to set the seed when the class object is initialized and then the fit function is called, so I am setting the NumPy random seed to a fixed seed: `np.random.seed(123)`

This seed is set globally in the first entry point of the application.

The problem is that the results of the forecasting are different between different machines, although we are running inside a Docker Image that depends on a Pipfile so all the dependencies have the same versions + the python version is the same as well (3.9):

```
numpy = "==1.22.3"
scikit-learn = "==1.1.1"
statsmodels = "==0.13.2"
scipy = "==1.9.3"
```

The differences in the forecasted values are also significant to our application for both algorithms. Example:

| Locally windows 10 | Azure |
| --- | --- |
| 8499 | 12693 |
| 140277 | 41278 |

Can anyone support this?

---

**Update** Code snippet + sample can be found here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pmdarima as pm
from pmdarima.arima.utils import ndiffs
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX

np.random.seed(123)

def train_sarima_model(df_historical: pd.DataFrame):
    historical_data = df_historical["value"].to_numpy()

    # select the best model trained on the historical data
    smodel = pm.auto_arima(
        historical_data,
        start_p=1,
        start_q=1,
        test="adf",
        max_p=3,
        max_q=3,
        m=12,
        start_P=0,
        seasonal=True,
        d=None,
        D=1,
        trace=True,
        error_action="ignore",
        suppress_warnings=True,
        stepwise=True
    )
    mod = SARIMAX(
        historical_data,
        order=smodel.order,
        seasonal_order=smodel.seasonal_order,
        enforce_stationarity=False,
        enforce_invertibility=False
    )
    best_model = mod.fit(disp=0)
    return best_model

df_forecasting = df[["date", "value"]]
df_forecasting = df_forecasting.sort_values(by=["date"], ascending=True)
df_forecasting.set_index("date", inplace=True)
best_model = train_sarima_model(df_forecasting)
forecasting_values = list(best_model.forecast(steps=forecasting_period))
```

```
{
    "balance": [
        {
            "date": "2020-07-21",
            "value": 0.0
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-07-22",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-07-23",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-07-24",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-07-25",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-07-26",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-07-27",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-07-28",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-07-29",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-07-30",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-07-31",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-01",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-02",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-03",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-04",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-05",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-06",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-07",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-08",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-09",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-10",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-11",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-12",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-13",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-14",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-15",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-16",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-17",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-18",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-19",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-20",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-21",
            "value": -3799.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-22",
            "value": -7598.4
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-23",
            "value": -7598.4
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-24",
            "value": -7598.4
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-25",
            "value": -7598.4
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-26",
            "value": -7598.4
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-27",
            "value": -7598.4
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-28",
            "value": -8199.33
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-29",
            "value": -8199.33
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-30",
            "value": -8199.33
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-08-31",
            "value": -8199.33
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-01",
            "value": -8199.33
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-02",
            "value": -8199.33
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-03",
            "value": -9084.37
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-04",
            "value": -9084.37
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-05",
            "value": -10582.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-06",
            "value": 3080.3
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-07",
            "value": 3080.3
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-08",
            "value": 38080.3
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-09",
            "value": 38080.3
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-10",
            "value": 38080.3
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-11",
            "value": 38080.3
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-12",
            "value": 38080.3
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-13",
            "value": 36951.98
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-14",
            "value": 36951.98
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-15",
            "value": 36951.98
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-16",
            "value": 35683.81
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-17",
            "value": 35683.81
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-18",
            "value": 35683.81
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-19",
            "value": 35683.81
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-20",
            "value": 35683.81
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-21",
            "value": 35683.81
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-22",
            "value": 31460.83
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-23",
            "value": 31460.83
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-24",
            "value": -41714.74
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-25",
            "value": -41714.74
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-26",
            "value": -46472.74
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-27",
            "value": -46472.74
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-28",
            "value": -47073.67
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-29",
            "value": -47304.67
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-30",
            "value": -47304.67
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-01",
            "value": -45426.27
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-02",
            "value": -45426.27
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-03",
            "value": -45426.27
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-04",
            "value": -46924.1
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-05",
            "value": -46924.1
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-06",
            "value": -46924.1
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-07",
            "value": -44681.6
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-08",
            "value": -44931.6
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-09",
            "value": -44931.6
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-10",
            "value": -49422.08
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-11",
            "value": -50228.33
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-12",
            "value": -50228.33
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-13",
            "value": -49350.63
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-14",
            "value": -49350.63
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-15",
            "value": -49350.63
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-16",
            "value": -49350.63
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-17",
            "value": -49363.73
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-18",
            "value": -49363.73
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-19",
            "value": -49530.26
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-20",
            "value": -49530.26
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-21",
            "value": -49530.26
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-22",
            "value": -49530.26
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-23",
            "value": -53329.46
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-24",
            "value": -53329.46
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-25",
            "value": -53135.66
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-26",
            "value": -53135.66
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-27",
            "value": -77135.66
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-28",
            "value": -77736.59
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-29",
            "value": -77736.59
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-30",
            "value": -77736.59
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-10-31",
            "value": -80083.59
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-01",
            "value": -80105.19
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-02",
            "value": -78731.24
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-03",
            "value": -78731.24
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-04",
            "value": -78807.11
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-05",
            "value": -80304.94
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-06",
            "value": -80304.94
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-07",
            "value": -80304.94
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-08",
            "value": -80878.69
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-09",
            "value": -80925.64
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-10",
            "value": -81305.64
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-11",
            "value": -80512.64
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-12",
            "value": -80512.64
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-13",
            "value": -80512.64
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-14",
            "value": -80512.64
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-15",
            "value": -84057.43
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-16",
            "value": -84057.43
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-17",
            "value": -84057.43
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-18",
            "value": -87557.43
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-19",
            "value": -92356.43
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-20",
            "value": -92356.43
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-21",
            "value": -92356.43
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-22",
            "value": -91356.43
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-23",
            "value": -96317.73
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-24",
            "value": -96317.73
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-25",
            "value": -99317.73
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-26",
            "value": -99317.73
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-27",
            "value": -97797.73
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-28",
            "value": -98398.66
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-29",
            "value": -104547.66
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-11-30",
            "value": -104547.66
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-01",
            "value": -104569.26
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-02",
            "value": -98420.26
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-03",
            "value": -98420.26
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-04",
            "value": -98420.26
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-05",
            "value": -99974.01
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-06",
            "value": -99974.01
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-07",
            "value": -102775.87
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-08",
            "value": -102775.87
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-09",
            "value": -102776.47
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-10",
            "value": -100968.77
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-11",
            "value": -100708.77
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-12",
            "value": -101976.77
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-13",
            "value": -102356.77
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-14",
            "value": -102356.77
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-15",
            "value": -98721.17
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-16",
            "value": -105721.17
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-17",
            "value": -106065.66
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-18",
            "value": -106065.66
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-19",
            "value": -106065.66
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-20",
            "value": -106065.66
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-21",
            "value": -106066.41
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-22",
            "value": -109865.61
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-23",
            "value": -111027.71
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-24",
            "value": -111027.71
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-25",
            "value": -111027.71
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-26",
            "value": -112047.23
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-27",
            "value": -119641.23
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-28",
            "value": -120242.16
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-29",
            "value": -120242.16
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-30",
            "value": -120242.16
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-12-31",
            "value": -120242.16
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-01",
            "value": -120263.76
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-02",
            "value": -113563.76
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-03",
            "value": -113563.76
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-04",
            "value": -113563.76
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-05",
            "value": -121368.63
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-06",
            "value": -121368.63
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-07",
            "value": -121368.63
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-08",
            "value": -134820.63
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-09",
            "value": -134820.63
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-10",
            "value": -136590.81
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-11",
            "value": -136590.81
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-12",
            "value": -137875.81
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-13",
            "value": -137875.81
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-14",
            "value": -138125.81
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-15",
            "value": -138127.26
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-16",
            "value": -138127.26
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-17",
            "value": -138127.26
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-18",
            "value": -138127.26
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-19",
            "value": -138127.26
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-20",
            "value": -138127.26
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-21",
            "value": -136651.06
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-22",
            "value": -137813.91
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-23",
            "value": -137813.91
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-24",
            "value": -137813.91
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-25",
            "value": -138063.91
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-26",
            "value": -138063.91
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-27",
            "value": -138063.91
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-28",
            "value": -138063.91
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-29",
            "value": -138063.91
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-30",
            "value": -138063.91
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-31",
            "value": -138063.91
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-01",
            "value": -138085.51
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-02",
            "value": -138461.51
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-03",
            "value": -138461.51
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-04",
            "value": -138461.51
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-05",
            "value": -103517.43
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-06",
            "value": -104615.43
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-07",
            "value": -104615.43
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-08",
            "value": -104615.43
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-09",
            "value": -103615.43
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-10",
            "value": -103615.43
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-11",
            "value": -104340.11
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-12",
            "value": -105660.51
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-13",
            "value": -106805.81
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-14",
            "value": -115238.45
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-15",
            "value": -115238.45
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-16",
            "value": -115238.45
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-17",
            "value": -115238.45
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-18",
            "value": -115238.45
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-19",
            "value": -115238.45
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-20",
            "value": -115238.45
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-21",
            "value": -115238.45
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-22",
            "value": -115238.45
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-23",
            "value": -115241.95
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-24",
            "value": -554.95
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-25",
            "value": -554.95
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-26",
            "value": -4.95
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-27",
            "value": -4.95
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-28",
            "value": -4.95
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-01",
            "value": 3726.85
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-02",
            "value": 3726.85
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-03",
            "value": 3726.85
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-04",
            "value": 3726.85
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-05",
            "value": 3726.85
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-06",
            "value": 3726.85
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-07",
            "value": 3726.85
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-08",
            "value": 3670.93
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-09",
            "value": 3670.93
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-10",
            "value": 3670.93
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-11",
            "value": 6465.25
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-12",
            "value": 5180.25
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-13",
            "value": 7230.25
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-14",
            "value": 7230.25
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-15",
            "value": 7210.3
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-16",
            "value": 7210.3
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-17",
            "value": 7210.3
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-18",
            "value": 7892.58
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-19",
            "value": 7892.58
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-20",
            "value": 7892.58
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-21",
            "value": 7892.58
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-22",
            "value": 7892.58
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-23",
            "value": 7314.48
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-24",
            "value": 7314.48
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-25",
            "value": 7314.48
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-26",
            "value": 7314.48
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-27",
            "value": 7314.48
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-28",
            "value": 7314.48
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-29",
            "value": 8514.48
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-30",
            "value": 9977.53
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-03-31",
            "value": 9957.58
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-01",
            "value": 9935.98
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-02",
            "value": 9935.98
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-03",
            "value": 9935.98
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-04",
            "value": 8412.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-05",
            "value": 8412.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-06",
            "value": 8412.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-07",
            "value": 8412.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-08",
            "value": 72412.2
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-09",
            "value": 72378.25
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-10",
            "value": 72378.25
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-11",
            "value": 72378.25
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-12",
            "value": 71093.25
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-13",
            "value": 71093.25
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-14",
            "value": 71092.75
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-15",
            "value": 71092.75
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-16",
            "value": 136685.95
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-17",
            "value": 137062.13
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-18",
            "value": 140697.76
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-19",
            "value": 140697.76
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-20",
            "value": 140697.76
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-21",
            "value": 140088.75
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-22",
            "value": 140088.75
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-23",
            "value": 113926.65
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-24",
            "value": 113926.65
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-25",
            "value": 96958.65
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-26",
            "value": 96958.65
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-27",
            "value": 96958.65
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-28",
            "value": 96956.65
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-29",
            "value": 96956.65
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-04-30",
            "value": 96956.65
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-05-01",
            "value": 96956.65
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-05-02",
            "value": 96956.65
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-05-03",
            "value": 96956.65
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-05-04",
            "value": 95432.87
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-05-05",
            "value": 95432.87
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-05-06",
            "value": 95465.28
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-05-07",
            "value": 95465.28
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-05-08",
            "value": 95465.28
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-05-09",
            "value": 95465.28
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-05-10",
            "value": 94740.6
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-05-11",
            "value": 94740.6
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-05-12",
            "value": 94740.6
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-05-13",
            "value": 91405.6
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-05-14",
            "value": 91405.6
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-05-15",
            "value": 91405.6
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-05-16",
            "value": 91405.6
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-05-17",
            "value": 91405.6
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I don't think either ARIMA or Linear Regression make use of random state. I'm pretty sure they're deterministic methods. That's why they don't provide the ability to set a random seed. Is `balanceOut` the result of one of those models, or is it the average of multiple models. If it's an average, can you provide the output for each model?

Comment: @NickODell thanks for your reply.  balanceOut is the immediate output and not the average, and those 2 output samples here are the ARIMA outputs from local vs. Azure.

Comment: That's pretty strange. I can't think of why that would vary so much. Can you post a reproducible example, with enough data/code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @NickODell Code and data sample are added.

Comment: I see you're using pmdarima to automatically pick the order and seasonal order of your arima model. Does it pick the same order and seasonal order locally and in Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @NickODell comment, the issue was solved as the following:

1. ARIMA/SARIMAX

for the ARIMA/SARIMAX model, a random state should be defined with a specific seed and then be passed to the `pm.auto_arima` function. The reason is that `pm.auto_arima` uses a `train_test_split` function (which usually takes a seed) to find the best model.

```
random_state = np.random.RandomState(123)
smodel = pm.auto_arima(
        df_historical.value,
        start_p=1,
        start_q=1,
        test="adf",
        max_p=3,
        max_q=3,
        m=12,
        start_P=0,
        seasonal=True,
        d=None,
        D=1,
        trace=True,
        error_action="ignore",
        suppress_warnings=True,
        stepwise=True,
        random_state=random_state
    )

mod = SARIMAX(
        historical_data,
        order=smodel.order,
        seasonal_order=smodel.seasonal_order,
        enforce_stationarity=False,
        enforce_invertibility=False
    )
best_model = mod.fit(disp=0)
```

2. Linear Regression

for the linear regression, the issue was solved by deactivating the intercept fitting since it contains a lot of averaging and shifting calculations and this causes some differences in the predicted values between different operating systems.

```
regr = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
regr.fit(x, y)
```